# Script to Read Videos and output information

Tags: bash, shell-script, video

I am working on a script that reads all folders inside a Movie folder and outputs the information for each video in a file.

The current one I have is this:

```sh
movies=0
rm movielist
for dir in Movies/*
do
  (cd "$dir" && pwd|cut -d \/ -f5|tr -s '\n' ', ' >> ../../movielist &&
  >> ../../movielist )
echo "Movie $movies - $dir ADDED!"
let movies=movies+1
done

rm moviefinal
cat movielist | while read MovieName;
do 
    echo "$MovieName" | cut -d ',' -f2 | cut -d 'x' -f2 | sort | uniq | while read MovieRes;
    do
        case $MovieRes in
        [461-660]*)
            echo "$MovieName,480p" >> moviefinal
        ;;
        [661-890]*)
            echo "$MovieName,720p" >> moviefinal
        ;;
        [891-1200]*)
            echo "$MovieName,1080p" >> moviefinal
        ;;
        *)
            echo "$MovieName,DVD" >> moviefinal
        ;;
        esac
    done    
done
```

Which reads from the **Movies** folder each movie (eg: Movies/The Matrix/Matrix.mkv) and sends it to a file called moviex inside the Movies folder. The info inside the file is something like this:

```
The Matrix, 1920x1080, MKV
The Matrix 2, 1280x720, AVI
....
```

What I want to add now is a way to read the Height and Width (Which are the SourceImageHeight and SourceImageWidth with exiftool) and do a CASE or IF where, if the height is X and width is Z then add to the output file another variable which is the quality (ie: 720p, 1080p, DVD...). The above would look something like this:

```
The Matrix, 1920x1080, MKV, 1080p
The Matrix 2, 1280x720, AVI, 720p
```

UPDATE - The script is now showing the Quality (720p, 1080p) but the CASE part is wrong. It sometimes grabs for example a 720 video and gives it a DVD quaility, when in fact, in the script I explicitly said 720.

Answer (score 1):

Well the finished script is this if anybody in the future would want to do the same:

```sh
movies=0
rm movielist
for dir in Movies/*
do
  (cd "$dir" && pwd|cut -d \/ -f5|tr -s '\n' ', ' >> ../../movielist &&
    exiftool * -t -s3 -ImageSize -FileType|tr -s '\t' ',' >> ../../movielist )
echo "Movie $movies - $dir ADDED!"
let movies=movies+1
done

rm moviefinal
cat movielist | while read MovieName;
do 
    echo "$MovieName" | cut -d ',' -f2 | cut -d 'x' -f2 | sort | uniq | while read MovieRes;
    do
        if (($MovieRes>=461 && $MovieRes<=660))
        then
            echo "$MovieName,480p" 
        elif (($MovieRes>=661 && $MovieRes<=890))
        then
            echo "$MovieName,720p" 
        elif (($MovieRes>=891 && $MovieRes<=1200))
        then
            echo "$MovieName,1080p"
        else
            echo "$MovieName,DVD" 
        fi >> moviefinal
    done    
done
```